# HTmlAgilityPack DocumentNode.SelectNodes return null

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape some stock quotes of a site.
There is one quote per webpage I am interested in. The webpages are the same in structure for each stock quotes. For about 10 of the quotes this works well, but for one HTmlAgilityPack DocumentNode.SelectNodes return null.

Obviously this has to be caused by something on the webpage, but I can't understand what.

This is my code where I am looking for the element surface:

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(URL].ToString());

 foreach (HtmlNode nody in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='surface']"))
        {
            //Do something!
        }
```

This URL works well:
https://www.avanza.se/borshandlade-produkter/etf-torg/om-fonden.html/630586/ishares-msci-brazil-small-cap-etf

This URL throws NullreferenceException:
https://www.avanza.se/borshandlade-produkter/etf-torg/om-fonden.html/454676/global-x-msci-portugal-etf

...even though I do find the surface element when examining the source code of the webpage.

Can you please help me understand why the surface element is not found in the second URL?

Update:After saving the documents returned from the two different URL, I compare them and I can see that the surface element is not present in "portugal". There is some kind of redirect, which I have to investigate.

Update 2: The error causing link used a redirect to another page. This was not possible to handle with my code, but I just updated the link to point to the redirect page and problem was solved!

Comment: Why use `SelectNodes` if you're trying to select a single node by the `surface` id? Why not `doc.GetElementById("surface")`?

Comment: Well, I am new to HtmlAgilityPack. I just used an example I found. I tested your suggestion but the same occurs. I have updated the original post with some new info.